# How is the list index out of range?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm playing around a bit in Tkinter python when I get this error for what I think is no reason whatsoever.

```
    print(self.entries[x])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

My code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.submit()

    def submit(self):
        for x in range(2):
            self.entries = []
            self.buttons = []
            e = Entry()
            self.entries.append(e)
            self.entries[x].grid(row=x, column=0)
            b = Button(text='SUBMIT', command=lambda x=x: print(self.entries[x].get()))
            self.buttons.append(b)
            self.buttons[x].grid(row=x, column=1)

root = Tk()
app = Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```

The goal is to make multiple rows of entries and submit buttons with this single loop. I have tried to remove all the self in front of everything in the function, but to no avail.

Everything works if the range() in the for loop has a 1, but not for any other number. Can someone please explain? My 1 year course in high school didn't set me up for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Move the `self.entries = []` and the `self.buttons = []` before the for loop

Comment: Also instead of `self.entries[x].grid(...)`, you can use `e.grid(...)` same fore `self.buttons[x].grid(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep resetting `self.entries` and `self.buttons` each time the for loop runs. You need to move the `self.entries = []` and `self.buttons = []` before the for loop like this:

```py
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        # self.master = master # Useless
        self.submit()

    def submit(self):
        self.entries = []
        self.buttons = []
        for x in range(2):
            e = Entry(self)
            e.grid(row=x, column=0)
            self.entries.append(e)
            b = Button(self, text="SUBMIT", command=lambda x=x: print(self.entries[x].get()))
            b.grid(row=x, column=1)
            self.buttons.append(b)

root = Tk()
app = Application(root)
app.pack()
app.mainloop()
```

Also another few things:

- Instead of `self.entries[x].grid(...)`, you can use `e.grid(...)`
- You never passed in anything for the `master` argument when creating the entries and buttons.
- You inherited from `tk.Frame` but never put anything inside it and you didn't even call `app.pack(...)`/`app.grid(...)`
- Also please you `import tkinter as tk` instead of `from tkinter import *`.

Comment: To be honest, the master and importing from tk.Frame are things that I don't understand at all. The docs just told me to do it... But thanks for the awesome answer.